# Sorting: An alternative to HashMaps and Sets?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I'm trying to make a free course in Coursera, named Algorithms, part 1. In one of the assignments we're asked devise and algorithm to find all sets of collinear points in a graph. Here's the link for more specifications:

https://coursera.cs.princeton.edu/algs4/assignments/collinear/specification.php.

In the class FastCollinearPoints, we're asked to implement the following algorithm:

> Think of p as the origin.
>
> For each other point q, determine the slope it makes with p.
>
> Sort the points according to the slopes they makes with p.
>
> Check if any 3 (or more) adjacent points in the sorted order have equal slopes with respect to p. If so, these points, together with p,
>   are collinear.

[image]

Here's part of the class I made:

```
    private ArrayList<LineSegment> segments = new ArrayList<>();
        private HashMap<Double, ArrayList<Point>> slopeEndPoints = new HashMap<>();

// finds all line segments containing 4 or more points
    public FastCollinearPoints(Point[] points) {
        if(points == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null Argument: points");
        int N = points.length;
        Point[] pointsCopy = Arrays.copyOf(points, points.length);
        Arrays.parallelSort(pointsCopy);
        checkCornerCases(pointsCopy);

        for(int p = 0; p < N-3; p++) {
            Point[] ptsInRange = Arrays.copyOfRange(pointsCopy, p, N);
            Arrays.parallelSort(ptsInRange, ptsInRange[0].slopeOrder());
            int first = 1, last = 2;
            while(last < ptsInRange.length) {
                double slope = ptsInRange[0].slopeTo(ptsInRange[first]);
                while(last < ptsInRange.length 
                        && Double.compare(slope, ptsInRange[0].slopeTo(ptsInRange[last])) == 0)
                    last++;
                if(last - first > 2)
                    if(isSelected(slope, ptsInRange, last-1))
                        segments.add(new LineSegment(ptsInRange[0], ptsInRange[last-1]));
                first = last;
                last++;
            }
        }


    }

    private boolean isSelected(double slope, Point[] points, int end) {
            ArrayList<Point> selection = this.slopeEndPoints.get(slope);
            if(selection == null) {
                selection = new ArrayList<Point>();
                selection.add(points[end]);
                this.slopeEndPoints.put(slope, selection);
                return true;
            }
            else if(selection.contains(points[end]))
                return false;
            else {
                selection.add(selection.size(), points[end]);
                this.slopeEndPoints.put(slope, selection);
                return true;
            }
```

When I submitted my answer, I get this feedback:

> FastCollinearPoints.java:9:17: Do not use the 'HashMap' data type on
>   this assignment. Hash tables have not yet been introdcued in the
>   course (and wont achieve the worst-case performance requirements).
>   Instead, use sorting. [Performance]

So I was wondering: what do they mean with "use sorting"? Can I get the same effect of the HashMap by sorting? How?

Comment: *"what do they mean with "use sorting""* Build a `List<Point>` and call `Collections.sort()` with a `Comparator` that sorts by "slope". Then iterate the list and (using same `Comparator`), find adjacent points that compare "equal" (`compare()` returns 0).

Answer (score 0):

Probably somebody would write the code here for you and I strongly believe it won't make you learn, so instead let's try understanding what's happening in the algorithm.

So there are two things (which you could have cleared in the question), but let's break it down here -

1. Finding all sets of collinear points in the graph
2. For a fixed point `P`, implementing the algorithm you just mentioned in question.

Let's start with Part 2 first: The java solution you posted is an overkill, you don't need `HashMaps` at all.

Consider this piece:

```
// declare Point P

class Point {
  int x, y;       // 
  double slope;   // slope = y/x
}

double getSlope(Point a) {
  return (double)(a.y - P.y) / (a.x - P.x);
}

// declare list of points as List<Point> ptList

Collections.sort(ptList, new Comparator<Point>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(Point a, Point b) {
    return getSlope(a) < getSlope(b);
  }
});


for(int i = 1; i < ptList.length(); i++) {
    if(getSlope(ptList[i]) == getSlope(ptList[i - 1]) {
       // this means points i, i - 1 have equal slopes
    }
}
```

This is based out of the fact that numbers which are equal are grouped together after sorting. For example, an unsorted array `[0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 3, 1, 1]` will look like this after sorting `[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]` and notice how equal elements are together.

Now part 1: We need to find all such sets. We will try to make each point in the given list `P`, and rest of the points which are not yet processed as set `Q`. Using the procedure above we can divide points set `Q` into collinear sets.

When you have done this for all `P`, you are done.

---

P.S. - Please don't compare double values directly using `val1 == val2`  because of floating point precisions it will fail. Use a threshold based comparison like `absolute(val1 - val2) < 10^(-9)`

More read:  https://howtodoinjava.com/java/basics/correctly-compare-float-double/